# Jenkins cannot find web.xml but Intellij can

Tags: java, jenkins, jetty, web.xml

I am running a test that reads web.xml as follows:

```
new URL(
    new ClassPathResource("com/jettyrule/testwebapp/web-inf/web.xml")
        .getURL(), "..");
```

My test passes in Intellij but when I run in Jenkins, I get this:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [com/jettyrule/testwebapp/web-inf/web.xml] cannot be resolved to URL
>   because it does not exist.

I have checked the project contents on Jenkins and the web.xml file is there at that location. Anyone know why Jenkins is different to local?

The only thing I can think of is the package is com/jettyrule/testwebapp/WEB-INF (uppercase). Should that matter?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the package was called WEB-INF and not web-inf. Jenkins is case-sensitive.